# Did Hannibal join Antiochus in order to get back at Rome, or was he merely escaping his political enemies in Carthage?

Tags: roman-republic, carthage

According to Livy's history of early Rome ([Book 33](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0148:book=33)), Hannibal was forced to flee Carthage in 195 BC after his disgruntled political enemies among the Punic aristocracy sent word to Rome accusing him of conspiring with King Antiochus III of the Seleucid Empire to wage war against the Roman Republic. Hannibal ended up seeking refuge with Antiochus and commanded the king's naval forces during the subsequent Roman-Seleucid War.

Did Hannibal intentionally join Antiochus in order to get back at Rome for his country's defeat in the Second Punic War (in line with his childhood oath to be an eternal enemy of Rome), or was he merely seeking personal security against his Carthaginian political enemies and the Roman envoys who wanted to take him into custody?

Comment: This is a *false dilemma* fallacy. Why does it have to be one or the other, rather than a fortuitous alignment of both?